# C++11 range-based цикл

Tags: c++, foreach, const

В каких случаях использовать данный синтаксис? Где использовать `const`, а где ссылку?

```
for (const auto& elem: коллекция)
{  ...  }
```

Мои подозрения, если употребить `const`, то в `elem` будет храниться константный объект, а если ссылку, то в `elem` будет храниться ссылка на константный объект. Если не употреблять этого всего, то в `elem` будет хранится копия объекта.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `const auto&` если объект не будет меняться в теле цикла и/или оптимизация операций копирования.
- `auto&` если необходимо изменить объект в коллекции.
- `auto` если объект будет изменяться, но его копия в коллекции должна остаться неизменной.

Comment: auto& вполне может дать ссылку на константу, например, если объект-коллекция константен в данном контексте.